# How to resolve java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumers.create(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/odata4j/consumer/ODataConsumer;

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, merge, odata4j

I am using odata4j library in my web project to merge the entity 
but i am getting this error in web project but if i try in standalone application then it works perfectly 
Can somebody tell me whats wrong i am doing here

```
String URL = "https://api.sqlazureservices.com/APService.svc/";
ODataConsumer oDataConsumers = ODataConsumers.create(URL);
OEntity entity = oDataConsumers.getEntity(tableName, id).execute();
```

Comment: NoSuchMethodError usually means you're running against a different version of the library from the one the code was compiled against.

Comment: Oh Thanks Ian i will try, But when i run in console program its working how that can be possible

Comment: Check that you don't have two different versions of the library in different places, e.g. if your container has a location for libraries that are shared among all webapps.

Answer (score 0):

Odata4j currently does not handle the response from a function call.

Check out the [reply here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031812/odata4j-consumer-function-call).

Comment: I think his code is not calling OData function/action. It's simple getEntity call.